# onClick not firing on React.js input radio button

Tags: reactjs, dom, dom-events

Moving the `onClick ={props.onPassFail}` fires when moved to the wrapping `<Label>`  but does not fire when attached to the `<Input>` control.  I ultimately want to fire on onChange event, and do not understand why Input is not registering onClick or onChange events.  I am following the convention for radio buttons required by Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.

How can I attach onClick and onChange directly to the `<Input>` control?

Code:

```
<div className="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label className="btn btn-secondary passfail passfail-fail" onClick={props.onPassFail}>
    <input type="radio" name="passfail" id="option1" autoComplete="off" /> Fail
  </label>
  <label className="btn btn-secondary passfail passfail-pass" onClick={props.onPassFail}>
     <input type="radio" name="passfail" id="option2" autoComplete="off"  /> Pass
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass onClick to input, not to label

Comment: The error is that passing onClick to the input does nothing.  @Amt Labib's solution is using a React component not a stateless function.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `onClick` and `onChange` directly on input control check the code below, it's fully working

The handlers of `onClick` and onChange are functions added in the component and inside these functions you can call any handler passed as `props`

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
        this.changed = this.changed.bind(this);
    }

    clicked(){
        console.log("clicked");
        //this.props.onPassFail();
    }

    changed(){
        console.log("changed");
        //this.props.onPassFail();
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit  , error } = this.props
        return (
            <label>
                <input type="radio" onClick={this.clicked} onChange={this.changed} />
            </label>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: My original question was unclear in stating that I am trying to do this in a stateless function, not a react component.  Is that possible?